# How to display a label with a variable value? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using NetBeans and JavaFX to create a minigame that have a Attack Button and a Enemy - just like Pokemon...

But I am Stuck trying to set a variable value (Variable 'hp' - value - 100) on a label to everytime I press the Attack button, the value of var 'hp' decreases by my damage value and the label show it's current 'hp'.

TL;DR - I need to display a variable value on a label on JavaFX

Thank you very much!

Comment: See [*JavaFX: Working with JavaFX UI Components: 3 Button*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm#CJHEEACB).

Comment: Are you using fxml or doing the JavaFX controls dynamically? If you have a reference to the Label you should do myLabel.setText(hp.toString())

Comment: If you create dynamically you have the reference already and if you use .fxml and scenebuilder you need to use the controller it provides for you to inject the label name, just make sure you give it an fxid in SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using SceneBuilder.

Your controller should have something like this at the top somewhere

```
@FXML
Label myLabel;
```

In order to change the text on the label you simply do this in the onAction for the button.

```
  @FXML
  void onAction(ActionEvent event) {
       myLabel.setText(hp.toString());
  }
```